# Pass array by reference and change its value

Tags: php, pass-by-reference, php-5.6

I have a basic question here about changing array values inside a function, let's say that I have the following array inside a class:

```
$my_array = array(1, 2, 3);
```

And then I have the following method which returns my array;

```
public function getAnArray()
{
    return $this->my_array;
}
```

and then I wanna change one value of **my_array** (2 for example to 7) like this (based on some business logic):

```
public function changeArray($my_array)
{
    $new_value = 7;

    foreach($my_array as $key => $value){
        if($value == 2){
            $my_array[$key] = $new_value; // Change the value of 2 to 7
        }
    }
}
```

So that **$my_array** now becomes (1, 7, 3)

I understand that I have to pass something by reference for this to work, but I don't know exactly how this should work.

Comment: https://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is what you want to do:

```
class Foo {
    protected $my_array = array(1, 2, 3);

    public function getAnArray() {
        return $this->my_array;
    }

    public function changeArray($new_value,$where_current_value) {
        foreach($this->my_array as $key => $value){
            if($value == $where_current_value){
                $this->my_array[$key] = $new_value; // Change the value of 2 to 7
            }
        }
    }
}

$a = new Foo();

var_dump($a->getAnArray());

$a->changeArray(7,2);

var_dump($a->getAnArray());
```

Result should be as desired:

> ```
> array(3) {
>   [0]=>
>   int(1)
>   [1]=>
>   int(2)
>   [2]=>
>   int(3)
> }
> array(3) {
>   [0]=>
>   int(1)
>   [1]=>
>   int(7)
>   [2]=>
>   int(3)
> }
> ```

Arrays in PHP are basically always accessed by reference, this is why you have to create real copies of an array manually if you want to.

Comment: Would be one of the ways I'd do this too, if not for pass-by-reference!

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to pass-by-reference and update the array within the class you have here, your code should look like this:

```
foreach($my_array as &$element) {
    if($element == 2) {
        $element = 7;
    }
}
```

This will modify the original array's contents, as requested.

Although, it looks like you're accessing this from within a class. If the `$this->my_array` is constant through this class, there should be no need to pass `$my_array` to the `changeArray( .. )` method. Leaving your class like this;

```
class Foo {

    public $my_array = [1, 2, 3];

    public function getAnArray() {
        return $this->my_array;
    }

    public function changeArray($find, $replace) {
        foreach($this->my_array as &$obj){
            if($obj == $find){
                $obj = $replace; // Change the value of 2 to 7
            }
        }
    }

}

$x = new Foo();

print_r($x->getAnArray());

$x->changeArray(2, 7);

print_r($x->getAnArray());
```

<sup>*As a rough example*</sup>